# Notepad ++ : How to Replace as the description

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++, replaceall

**I have lines like these**

```
abye/>abye
abys/>abys
aced/>aced
aces/>aces
```

**I want it like this**

```
abye
abys
aced
aces
```

Is it possible? If it is then please someone show me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would remove all the characters from  start upto the `/>`

Regex:

```
^.*\/>
```

REplacement string:

```
Empty string
```

**OR**

The below regex would remove all the characters from   `/>` upto the end.

Regex:

```
\/>.*$
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `\/>` matches the literal `/>` symbols.
- `.*` matches any character  but not of new line character.
- `$` End of the line.

By replacing all the matched characters with an empty string, you get only the part before `/>`

Comment: Well by the way. My curious mind wants to know what does it calls? I mean by what name this replacing method is called ?

Comment: Added some more explanation. `^` means start and `$` means end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*)(?=\/).*$
```

You can try this.Replace by

`$1`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/32